# Unrealistic predictions from ML due to high differences in the PCA results of training and prediction data sets

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, pca, predictive-models, dimensionality-reduction

I have a very high-dimensional training set (~300D) and the predictors are highly correlated. Therefore, I ran `PCA` on the training data and it turns out that 6 `PC`s are enough to explain ~99% of the variation in the training set.

Hence, I kept only those 6 `PC`s as my predictors for machine learning (`ML`) model training. The 6 `PC`s (first 6 examples) look like this:

```
|        PC1|       PC2|        PC3|        PC4|        PC5|        PC6|
|----------:|---------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
|  -9.771549| -3.827747|  2.9245668| -0.5665935|  0.1713290|  0.4544728|
|  15.460740|  4.113467| -0.1197129|  0.8851271| -0.3868882|  0.7598501|
| -17.782880|  7.538710|  6.9293371| -1.2879122|  0.2715957| -0.5893660|
| -24.981467|  7.900724|  3.4624333| -1.4603620| -0.3122299|  0.1197103|
|  11.228855|  1.998577| -1.0166994| -0.3488780| -0.4519286| -0.0417837|
|   9.358533|  1.467957| -0.6097303| -0.4238638| -0.2418337|  0.2840885|
```

I made the exact same preprocessing steps for the validation and testing sets based on the training set (e.g. using the scaling factors - mean and standard deviation of training set, not validation and testing sets explicitly) as this is suggested. The `PCA` results for validation and testing sets seem very similar although I did not explicitly perform `PCA` for them.

I trained `ANN` on the training set, and tested on the validation and testing sets and the model seems to work very well on these sets.

Now, I have another data set on which I have to make predictions using the trained `ANN` model. I used the exact same transformation (scaling and `PCA` based on the training set) to get 6 PCs for this data set. But, the 6 `PC`s look very different from the `PCA` results of training and testing sets:

```
|       PC1|       PC2|       PC3|      PC4|       PC5|      PC6|
|---------:|---------:|---------:|--------:|---------:|--------:|
| -13245.26| -22081.56| -43410.22| 48645.37| -48980.44| 53596.35|
| -24146.61| -15982.04| -41161.53| 52007.29| -49452.43| 52105.31|
| -17232.47| -18435.81| -39299.39| 47905.61| -51266.76| 52223.69|
| -14585.95| -18612.40| -41111.39| 50026.41| -46628.30| 51840.56|
| -18974.25| -18848.59| -41187.38| 47901.96| -49822.84| 51848.54|
| -30657.77| -12755.27| -41228.71| 52902.16| -52276.29| 53275.37|
```

As you can probably guess, `ANN` gives me a very unrealistic predictions when I use the model to predict on this data set. And I do not have labels for this data set as the labels are what I have to predict.

`ANN` I have built is a multi-output regression model and although it does really well on the training, validation and testing sets, it gives me very unrealistic predictions for the data set I have to make predictions on.

Could these differences in the `PCA` results indicate that the data sets are from completely different distributions? And should I perform `PCA` on this data set explicitly and extract the first 6 `PC`s for prediction?

**UPDATE**: I performed `PCA` (with scaling and centering) on prediction set (the one without labels) without using the same training set `PCA` scaling and transformation. Then, I took the first 6 `PC`s and threw the rest. This time, the result looks much closer to the `PCA` result than before:

```
|      PC1|       PC2|      PC3|        PC4|       PC5|        PC6|
|--------:|---------:|--------:|----------:|---------:|----------:|
| 2.669013| -5.466714| 1.466906| -0.3025037| -3.099849|  0.0458244|
| 4.783994| -5.949396| 2.503893| -0.3880082| -2.808889|  0.2684732|
| 2.974174| -5.047682| 1.463603| -0.3253319| -3.205017| -2.0727434|
| 2.291158| -4.516547| 1.893270| -0.4827036| -3.425757| -0.3900811|
| 3.801425| -5.513287| 2.325632| -0.3225131| -3.366994|  0.2016989|
| 5.836599| -5.920547| 2.343807| -0.2373246| -3.736375|  0.7952611|
```

When I use the trained model on this version of the data set I get somewhat more realistic results (relatively). However, as most of the experts do not recommend this (running `PCA` explicitly on the "prediction" sets), I am not sure if the results could be realiable?

Comment: By the looks of it, the distribution of your new data is very far from the old data, so it's a bit hopeless (otherwise you wouldn't have such big means in the new processed data). You should check if the mean and standard deviations are at least of the same magnitude across datasets. Besides that, I find it very unlikely that an ANN is the best model for such a low dimensionality.

Comment: This seems like a good example of "covariate shift". Are you certain that the model is applied in an environment similar to the one the training data came from? Was the data capture pipeline the same?

Comment: @usεr11852 the training set was generated using very well-established physical simulations. So I am sure there are uncertainties in the simulated data, but also there are noise in the real data that I want to make predictions on. So, I cannot be too certain, but I really hope that the simulations represent what happens in nature to some degree. Also, please see UPDATE in the original post